# How to apply a tokenizer to a tf.data.Dataset object?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm currently working on sequence classification task where I'm trying to classify a sentence into a 0/1/2 label using Transfer Learning.

I download the `financial_phrasebank` as a HuggingFace dataset object and I want to convert this object to a `tf.data.Dataset` object and then perform my preprocessing tasks - shuffling, train-test split, tokenization and then passing it on to a model.

```
dataset = load_dataset("financial_phrasebank","sentences_allagree")

# Creating a TFDS object
tfds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.array(dataset['sentence']), np.array(dataset['label'])))

# Shuffling and creating the train and test sets
tfds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataset), seed=101)
train_dataset = tfds.take(len(dataset)*0.7) 
test_dataset = tfds.skip(len(dataset)*0.7)

# Tokenizer for the data
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
```

How do I send my tfds object to the tokenizer? I'm thinking of implementing the `.map()` method on the object, but not sure how to proceed.